# html data not sent when file attachement in php mail

Tags: php

I am working on attachment of mail in php

```
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
```

this only attach a file to mail.

```
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
```

2nd one only display data in mail.

but i want both attach a file and html data displayed in mail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want do make your message be HTML only, say your attachment is of type application/octet-stream then you need a message structure like:

```
multipart/mixed {
    text/html
    application/octet-stream
}
```

If you want your message to be plain-text/HTML alternatives, with an attachment, then you need a nested-multipart message structure like this:

```
multipart/mixed {
    multipart/alternative {
        text/plain
        text/html
    }
    application/octet-stream
}
```